# New parameter on addRemoteStore() datastore's Type

Tags: datastore, wakanda

In Wakanda Enterprise 2.2.1, when I try to connect to a remote 4D datastore, I get this error:

> The datastore's type "wakanda" is not available

The object passed to `addRemoteStore()` to get the remote datastore is:

```
{
    hostname: "myserver:8050",
    jsFile: "targetDS.js",
    password: "mypassword",
    ssl: false,
    timeout: 15,
    type: "4D",
    user: "myuser"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution found:

This turns out to be related to licensing. In addition to 4D Mobile connector, addRemoteStore() also requires Wakanda connector to access 4D datastore.

The method is working as in V1 with the added Wakanda connector license. Please feel free to reach out to Wakanda support or your 4D sales rep for the updated license.

Updated post:

I tested in V 2.2.1 and received the same error. The same code in v1.1.5 works without any error.

Wakanda documentation including v1 to v2 migration notes do not report changes in addRemoteStore().

I reported this on GitHub issues as a bug. The engineering team will look into this. You can track the status using the following link: https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues/221

-----------------------Original Post----------------------------
Is this solution upgraded or new?

In 2.2.1 local model and remote model have their own set of model files including a config.waConfig, which defines the configurations of 4D Mobile connection. The main model has to be local and remote model needs to be a new model:
[image]

Please check if you have that file in your Remote model for 4D Mobile and whether its values conflict with values passed to addRemoteStore().

Comment: I use addRemoteStore() to access several 4D Databases. Using similar object, get same result: `{type:"4D",group:NombreTienda,connection:{user:"xxxx",password:"xxxxx",hostname:host,timeout:60}};`error.message:
"The datastore's type "wakanda" is not available"

Comment: this is upgrade solution but i´m testing addRemoteStore() isolated